# Plot doesn't continue after killing Darko in GTA IV

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

A couple days ago, I finished the mission called That Special Someone and I decided to kill Darko but with a weapon other than a pistol. What do I do? I didn't get a call from Pegorino like the wiki says I do. Waiting isn't the answer because already did while doing the Cop Side Missions.

What do I do?!

Comment: Don't you have any more missions to do with another character? Try to start another mission maybe it'll fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have any more missions >.< I sopose to get a call from Pegorino like the wiki says I do. Waiting will not be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say either

- Reload to a previous save and *do not* kill him
- Call Pegornino, Roman, Mallorie, or any other key characters to the story at that time
- Continue waiting. Maybe try sleeping (not saving, just sleeping) and run around for ~2 gaming hours, rinse, repeat.